# go.Box names editing

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Here is my code for some NBA project:

```
fig = make_subplots(
    rows = 1, cols = 5,
    )

fig.add_trace(
    go.Box(x=per_game_player['HOF'], y=per_game_player['trb'], name ='Rebounds'),
    row = 1, col = 1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Box(x=per_game_player['HOF'], y=per_game_player['ast'], name = 'Assists'),
    row = 1, col = 2
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Box(x=per_game_player['HOF'], y=per_game_player['stl'], name = 'Steals'),
    row = 1, col = 3
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Box(x=per_game_player['HOF'], y=per_game_player['blk'], name = 'Blocks'),
    row = 1, col = 4
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Box(x=per_game_player['HOF'], y=per_game_player['pts'], name = 'Points'),
    row = 1, col = 5,
    
)

hovertemp = '<b>%{customdata}: </b> %{y} <br>'


fig.update_traces(
                  showlegend=False,
                  customdata = per_game_player['player'],
                  hovertemplate = hovertemp,
)

fig.update_layout(title_text = 'top stats')
fig.show();
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Do you have any ideas how can I replace '0' and '1' on the horizontal line?
'0' and '1' also appear on hover once I slide through the chart - but not on the outliers.

My table head:

```
{'player_id': {0: 2218, 1: 3168, 2: 2560, 3: 3228, 4: 4374},
 'player': {0: 'A.C. Green',
  1: 'A.J. Bramlett',
  2: 'A.J. English',
  3: 'A.J. Guyton',
  4: 'A.J. Hammons'},
 'g': {0: 1278.0, 1: 8.0, 2: 151.0, 3: 80.0, 4: 22.0},
 'fg': {0: 3.56, 1: 0.5, 2: 4.09, 3: 2.08, 4: 0.77},
 'fga': {0: 7.2, 1: 2.62, 2: 9.39, 3: 5.5, 4: 1.91},
 'trb': {0: 7.41, 1: 2.75, 2: 2.09, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.64},
 'ast': {0: 1.1, 1: 0.0, 2: 2.12, 3: 1.84, 4: 0.18},
 'stl': {0: 0.81, 1: 0.12, 2: 0.38, 3: 0.25, 4: 0.05},
 'blk': {0: 0.43, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.16, 3: 0.15, 4: 0.59},
 'pts': {0: 9.65, 1: 1.0, 2: 9.95, 3: 5.52, 4: 2.18},
 'all_star': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'outliers': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'HOF': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}}
```

Thx.

Comment: can you include a sample of your `per_game_player` dataframe? this would help us reproduce your error and debug what's happening. you can include the output from `per_game_player.head().to_dict()` into the question

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply just alter the data in your dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
per_game_player['HOF'] = np.where(per_game_player['HOF'] == 1, 'HOF', 'Not HOF')
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Worked. However I was not altering the table but put your proposition inside each fig.add_trace brackets so x=np.where(per_game_player['HOF'] == 1, 'HOF', 'Not HOF')

Comment: ah ok. Same concept.